# Bootstrap Modal doesn't close

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div id="im_modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Image" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" class="btn pull-left" href="javascript:close_preview()">Cancel</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">OK</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function close_preview() {
    $("#im_modal").modal("hide");
}
```

The function close_preview is being called, but doesn't close the modal.

Comment: Do you have the ids duplicated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work, probably the positioning of the function `close_preview` is not where it is supposed to be. But there is another way without using any methods/events you can add `data-dismiss` attribute to the button.

```
<a type="button" class="btn pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WafH4/)**

Comment: @user2653179 You are welcome. Do you see any thing in the console? any errors? Do you have the ids duplicated?

Comment: @user2653179 can you replicate the issue in the fiddle posted in my example probably i can help find out the issue.

Comment: @user2653179 you had a syntax error in the fiddle code otherwise it works.. http://jsfiddle.net/uPF65/

Answer (score 1):

For people using Coffeescript with the **hide** event, be careful with the implicit return. It interrupts the event's propagation. Be sure to return the event.

```
$('#myModal').on 'hide.bs.modal',(e)->
  //something
  return e
```